# I am using Python on Visual Studio Code to import an excel file but I am getting an import error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip

I want to read the data on an excel file within a F drive. I am using python on Visual Studio Code to try achieve this however I am getting an error as seen in the pictures below. I installed pandas but I still get an error. How can I fix this issue?

[Coding Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFyH4.png)

[Installed Pandas Library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1aiN.png)

I tried closing and opening visual studio. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling pandas.

[Python on Computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3xEp.png)

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python installed on your system? Choosing the right interpreter might solve it.It's [E0401 error](https://vald-phoenix.github.io/pylint-errors/plerr/errors/imports/E0401.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to open terminal in VS Code, and run `pip freeze` (and `pip3 freeze`). Check if you find pandas in the results, it won't. That must be because you'd have multiple installations of Python on your system. You may do any one of the below -

1. Get rid of all but one Python installation.
2. Install pandas on the VS Code installed python instance.
3. Configure the same installation of python that is referenced by your command prompt. (choose the correct python interpreter from VS Code Command Palette)

Comment: I ran both pip and pip3 freeze and I found pandas on both along with other libraries. Also, how do I configure the same installation of python?

Comment: Press `Ctrl+Shift+P` (⌘⇧P in Mac) to open Command Palette in VS Code. Type `Python: Select Interpreter` and hit return. You will be able to choose from the available python instances. [full source article](https://kmahireddy123123.medium.com/python-interpreter-in-visual-studio-code-ec4433e48f4#:~:text=Select%20a%20Python%203%20Python%20interpreter%20from%20inside,Select%20Python%20Environment%20option%20on%20the%20Status%20Bar.)

Answer (score 0):

To read an Excel file with Python, you need to install the pandas library. To install pandas, open the command line or terminal and type:

pip install pandas

Once pandas is installed, you can read an Excel file like this:

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('file_name.xlsx')

print(df)

You should also make sure that the file path is correct and that you have the correct permissions to access the file.
If you are still having issues, try using the absolute file path instead of a relative file path.

Comment: I have installed the pandas library. As you can see from the second picture attached.